# Convert Json array of objects to most suitable .Net collection

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have the following Json collection and I need to represent it as a .Net collection. Esentially it is a key-value pair list with the keys (col) possibly having dublicates (dictionary is out at this stage).

I sorting and grouping would be nice but not essential. Can any help identify what the best .Net enumeration would be the best fit please?

```
[
    {
        "col": "thiscol",
        "val": "thisval"
    },
    {
        "col": "thiscol",
        "val": "thisval2"
    },
    {
        "col": "thiscol2",
        "val": "thisval2"
    },
    {
        "col": "thiscol3",
        "val": "thisval3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourstring);
foreach (var item in dynObj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.col + " " + item.val);
}
```

**or**

```
JArray jArray = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourstring);
var newlist = jArray.OrderByDescending(x => x["val"]).ToArray();
```

**or**

```
JArray jArray = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourstring);
dynamic dynObj1 = jArray.OrderByDescending(x => x["val"]);
foreach (var item in dynObj1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.col + " " + item.val);
}
```

**or** with built-in JavaScriptSerializer & `dynamic`

```
dynamic dynObj2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<object>>(yourstring);
foreach (var item in dynObj2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["col"] + " " + item["val"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookup in this case, basically a dictionary that allows multiple values for each key - with Linq you can project to a lookup using `ToLookup()`. Note that lookups are immutable though - that might not fit your bill.

Alternatively of course you can just use a `Dictionary<T,IList<U>>` (or `IEnumerable<U>`) using a *collection* as your value type - dictionaries are flexible like that.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<YourObject>` where `YourObject` is a class you define to hold these values. I recommend using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/documentation) to parse the json. Then you can just use linq to manage the IEnumerable you get back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

`JArray arr = JArray.Parse(Your string);`

After that using for loop to get the values,